# Using a hidden form field

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am using a hidden form field and populating it with data from my JQuery code onSubmit. The problem is, the JQuery populates BOTH Type="Hidden" fields. I only want it to populate the name="moment" one, How can I fix this?

Here is my html:

```html
<form method="post" action="momentactions.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="<?php echo $album_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="moment">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my JQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    values = [];
    $('#container-top img').each(function() {
    values.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
$('input[type=hidden]').val(JSON.stringify(values));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as:

```
input[type="hidden"][name="moment"]
```

but still - it's not a good idea to extract all the values, serialize them, and send serialized

Comment: Any explanations on downvote? Or is it just another silly mass downvoter that didn't like truth in my comments? :)))

Comment: @zerkms +1, the down vote was unnecessary as this is the correct selector. Perhaps indicate in your answer that its just the selector?

Comment: @Mark: I'm sure it's one of my haters ;-) I prefer telling the truth in the comments so people don't like me ;-)

Comment: @zerkms there are also those that down vote other answers when they've answered a question. Not saying anyone here has done that though :)

Comment: _"I prefer telling the truth in the comments so people don't like me"_ - Did you mean "People don't like me because I tell the truth in comments"? I don't worry about unexplained downvotes anymore - I've had enough of those on answers that I know are correct (even on accepted answers) that it's clear some people just downvote randomly and/or out of spite. Or maybe the downvoters genuinely believe they're right, and they're the same people who post incorrect answers... +1 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

This line of code

```
$('input[type=hidden]')
```

says "Give me all input elements with a type of hidden" since you only want one of them you can do a few different things.

You can give your desired input field an ID and then use the jQuery ID selector (#):

```
$('#idgoeshere')
```

or you can give your desired input field a class and use the class selector (.):

```
$('.classgoeshere')
```

or you can keep your current html and use an attribute selector which is just like your current selector only a different attribute:

```
$('input[name="moment"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('input[type=hidden][name=moment]').val(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Also do not forget to close the input tags..

```
$('input[name=moment]')
$('input[name=moment]:hidden')
```

are all valid selectors..

Comment: Input tags don't need to be closed (unless you're using xhtml, of course, but otherwise it could be argued that it is wrong to close them).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add id="moment" on your input tags

```
<input type="hidden" name="moment" />
```

change it to

```
<input type="hidden" name="moment" id="moment" />
```

so on your codes, you can just use

```
$('input#moment').val(JSON.stringify(values));
```

Comment: While that would also work, it is not necessary, name attribute would work just as well since its already there.

Comment: if selector used is simple, it would faster to run. and it could be also be easier to maintain

Comment: I did not down vote. Just pointing something out. I don't down vote unless the answer is actually incorrect.